# SQL - convert letters to numbers

Tags: sql

I am tasked do convert letter grades (A,B+,D-,...) to numeric gades. A would be 1, B = 2,.. .The + would mean subtracting 0.3 and the - adding 0.3 (e.g. B- = 2.3 and D+ = 3.7)
Is there any query to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Why would A be 1 and not 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a mapping table and join on `LEFT(letter, 1)`. Then use a `CASE` to add or remove 0.3 in function of the `RIGHT(letter, 1)`

```sql
WITH
grades(letter) AS (
    VALUES ('A'), ('A+'), ('B'), ('B-'), ('D+'), ('F-')
),
mapping(letter, num) AS (
    VALUES ('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4), ('E', 5), ('F', 6)
)
SELECT
    grades.letter AS grade,
    CASE 
        WHEN RIGHT(grades.letter, 1) = '+' THEN mapping.num - 0.3
        WHEN RIGHT(grades.letter, 1) = '-' THEN mapping.num + 0.3
        ELSE mapping.num
    END AS num
FROM
    grades
JOIN
    mapping ON mapping.letter = LEFT(grades.letter, 1);
```

Result:

```
 grade | num
-------+-----
 A     |   1
 A+    | 0.7
 B     |   2
 B-    | 2.3
 D+    | 3.7
 F-    | 6.3
(6 rows)
```